# Is it is possible to press the keyboard key by javascript code

Tags: javascript

Is it is possible to press the keyboard key by javascript code????
For Example I have a button and I want when a user press it some key automatically pressed of keyboard which I require.

Comment: Which key you want to press?

Comment: The button on the keyboard won't physically move, no... ;)